# How to get child iframe id?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ext.net

I have 3 iframe and now trying to access the last iframe.
I've tried the below code :

for parent way

```
window.parent.document
```

i call the last iframe using

```
        <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Title="Vessel Certificate 
          Border="false" Height="370" MarginSpec="0 0 0 0"  Plain="true" Frame="true" >                                                                                                       
             <Loader ID="Loader2" Width="970"  Height="370" runat="server"             
                 Url="../../VOS/vos002.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true"   >
                <LoadMask ShowMask="true" /> 
             </Loader>                      
        </ext:Panel>
```

In js i use this method but it show undefined

```
var iframeID = $('iframe', window.document).attr('id');
```

Have any idea how to get current iframe id or the child iframe id.

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML and the javascript in context.

Comment: I'm using this way to call the last iframe                      <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Title="Vessel Certificate "     Border="false" Height="370" MarginSpec="0 0 0 0"  Plain="true" Frame="true" >                                                                                  <Loader ID="Loader2" Width="970"  Height="370" runat="server"        Url="../../VOS/vos002.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true"   >
               <LoadMask ShowMask="true" />    
    </Loader> 
</ext:Panel>

Comment: Java Script  var iframeID = $('iframe', window.parent.document).attr('id');

Comment: You should update your question to include this information.

Comment: Done do you have any idea on how to do it

Comment: not sure what templating language this is but the attribute you are selecting is 'id' but the attribute on your element is ID. Try: var iframeID = $('iframe', window.document).attr('ID');

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$('html').find('iframe').last().attr('id')

Comment: it prompt undefined